# Process 60k rows of excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-science, xlrd

Here, I have multiple excel sheet in multiple subdirectories. The total number of rows here is close to 60k.

**My code is:-**

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(path,keep_default_na=False,dtype=str) 
            for path in glob.iglob(f'{directory}/**/MUMBAI.xlsx', recursive=True)],
           ignore_index=True)
```

The problem is it takes a total of **3:30 Minutes** to execute. How can I load is much efficiently and fast?

I'm Thankful for the support from the community.

Comment: Have 1 data file. we had one csv file with 10mb that got sliced...

Comment: If you have to load the dataset once e.g. the data does not change often, I would not optimize anything. The time spend is just not worth it.  Instead save the loaded data into something better usable like .csv or .pickel. Than you can reload the data easily for your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to load it a lot of times, then run a one-time process to convert xlsx files to csv and load them. CSV load should be much faster than xlsx.